# How to collide two CCNODE object and CCSPRITE in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am developing a game where i have my game character in a class that implements CCNODE. And i have one CCSPRITE in other class so how can i get collision between these two.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to check the bounding boxes for an intersection.

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect([yourNode boundingBox], [yourSprite boundingBox])) {    
    //Handle collision
}
```